# Issue with Handler. thread exiting with uncaught exception.

Tags: java, android, multithreading

don't hesitate me, it's my first program. I try to send the message from one thread to another, however it fails on receiving. Here is a log from crash.

```
04-15 18:29:43.610 14765-15803/annikov.dd E/PositionConnection: Updating message: 50385
04-15 18:29:43.630 14765-15803/annikov.dd E/PositionConnection: mUpdateHandler { when=-9m0s379ms barrier=0 }
04-15 18:29:43.630 14765-15803/annikov.dd E/PositionConnection: mUpdateHandler.getdata Bundle[{pos=50385}]
04-15 18:29:43.640 14765-15803/annikov.dd W/dalvikvm: threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4153abc0)
04-15 18:29:43.660 14765-15803/annikov.dd E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-194
                                                            Process: annikov.dd, PID: 14765
                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                at annikov.dd.PositionConnection.updateMessages(PositionConnection.java:92)
                                                                at annikov.dd.PositionConnection$PositionClient$ReceivingThread.run(PositionConnection.java:242)
                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
04-15 18:29:43.970 14765-14808/annikov.dd I/NsdHelper: Discovery stopped: _http._tcp.
04-15 18:29:45.450 14765-14765/annikov.dd D/PositionClient: Socket getted
04-15 18:29:45.470 14765-14807/annikov.dd E/PositionConnection: Error creating ServerSocket: 
                                                                java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
                                                                    at libcore.io.Posix.accept(Native Method)
                                                                    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.accept(BlockGuardOs.java:55)
                                                                    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:98)
                                                                    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:203)
                                                                    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:128)
                                                                    at annikov.dd.PositionConnection$PositionServer$ServerThread.run(PositionConnection.java:152)
                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
04-15 18:29:45.470 14765-14807/annikov.dd W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
04-15 18:29:45.470 14765-14807/annikov.dd W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.accept(Native Method)
04-15 18:29:45.470 14765-14807/annikov.dd W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.accept(BlockGuardOs.java:55)
04-15 18:29:45.480 14765-14807/annikov.dd W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:98)
04-15 18:29:45.480 14765-14807/annikov.dd W/System.err:     at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:203)
04-15 18:29:45.480 14765-14807/annikov.dd W/System.err:     at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:128)
04-15 18:29:45.490 14765-14807/annikov.dd W/System.err:     at annikov.dd.PositionConnection$PositionServer$ServerThread.run(PositionConnection.java:152)
04-15 18:29:45.490 14765-14807/annikov.dd W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
04-15 18:34:44.160 14765-15803/annikov.dd I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14765 SIG: 9
```

It's the sender's part of code:

```
public class PositionConnection {

    private Handler mUpdateHandler;
```

...

```
public synchronized void updateMessages(int position, boolean local) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Updating message: " + position);


    Bundle messageBundle = new Bundle();
    messageBundle.putInt("pos", position);

    Message message = new Message();
    message.setData(messageBundle);
    Log.e(TAG, "mUpdateHandler " + message);
    Log.e(TAG, "mUpdateHandler " + message.getData());
    mUpdateHandler.sendMessage(message);              <---here it is crashed
    //mUpdateHandler.sendEmptyMessage(30450);


}
```

And this is from receiver:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener, SensorEventListener, NsdHelper.DiscoverListener {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private SeekBar channel4PositionBar, channel5PositionBar, channel6PositionBar;
    private MaestroSSC maestroSSC;

    NsdHelper mNsdHelper;
    PositionConnection mConnection;
    private Handler mUpdateHandler;
```

...

```
mUpdateHandler = new Handler()

{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        int position = msg.getData().getInt("pos");

        if (position >= 50000) {
            maestroSSC.setTarget(5, position - 50000);
            servo2value.setText(String.valueOf(position - 50000));
            channel6PositionBar.setProgress(position - 50000);
        } else if (position >= 40000) {
            maestroSSC.setTarget(4, position - 40000);
            servo1value.setText(String.valueOf(position - 40000));
            channel5PositionBar.setProgress(position - 40000);
        } else if (position >= 30000) {
            pwmvalue.setText(String.valueOf(position - 30000));
            maestroSSC.setTarget(3, position - 30000 + 1200);
            channel4PositionBar.setProgress(position - 30000);
        }
        //setSeekBarProgressIgnoreListener(position);
    }
};
```

Can anybody figure out what's wrong here? I really don't know how to proceed further *(

Comment: Where are you initializing `mUpdateHandler` in `PositionConnection`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `NullPointerException` at `annikov.dd.PositionConnection.updateMessages(PositionConnection.java:92)`. `mUpdateHandler` being null is the only possibility with your `updateMessages` code for `PositionConnection`

Comment: The same occurs if I send not null:

Comment: mUpdateHandler.sendEmptyMessage(30450)

Comment: I'm saying that `mUpdateHandler` is `null`. Can you post the whole code for `PositionConnection`?